# Unexpected keyword end error?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to print a chess board with `input(n,m)`. `n` represents columns, `m` represents rows. For example, `"4,3"` should output:

```
0101
1010
0101
```

My code gives an "unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end" error:

```
def zero_col(n)
  n.times{|x| print n%2}
end
def fir_col(n)
  n.times{|x| x%2==0 ? print 1 : print 0}
end
def chess(input)
  n,m=input[0].to_i, input[2].to_i
  m.times{|x| x%2==0 ? zero_col(n) : fir_col(n)}
end
chess("3,2")
```

It also contains another error:

```
syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
  n.times{|x| x%2==0 ? print 1 : print 0}
                            ^
```

Am I using `?:` wrong?

Comment: Methods in Ruby start with `def`, not `function`.

Comment: Yes! I can't believe I made that mistake

Comment: In future please post by adhering what mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question should be clear to all readers.

Comment: Don't use ternary (`?:`) for flow control. In general it's avoided in Ruby, and when it's used, use it for simple tests returning a different result, similar to a single-line `if`/`else`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use ternary (`?:`) for flow control.

In general it's avoided in Ruby, and when it's used, use it for simple tests returning a different result, similar to a single-line `if`/`else`.

```
4.times{ |x| 
  print x%2==0 ? 1 : 0
}
```

Also, use whitespace liberally because it aids readability. For instance, "isthisreadable", "or is this"?

And, use parenthesis to help define the logic from the results in a ternary. It's not absolutely necessary syntactically, but it helps the readability.

```
4.times{ |x| 
  print (x % 2 == 0) ? 1 : 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby methods are declared with `def` keyword so change from `functions` to `def`.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 n.times { |x| x%2==0 ? print 1 : print 0 }
 # actually parsed as
 # n.times { |x| x%2==0 ? print(1 : print 0}), which is invalid syntactically.
```

to

```
 n.times { |x| x%2==0 ? print(1) : print(0) }
```

Comment: Thank you! I have another question: why does zero_col(3) output "111" instead of "010"?

Comment: @user3366240 Because you are printing `n%2` (the method argument) and not `x%2` (the enumerator), within the block.